# How to add a declared function into tinymce.init

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-plugins

I'm trying to reuse some code for the different types of tinyMCE I have (simple, advanced, expert...).

For each type I have a `tinymce.init({ })`, and in each of them I use the paste plugin with a paste_preprocess function. As I'm using the same function for all the tinymce.init I have, I've tried to declare my function as a normal one:

```
function myFunction(pl, o) { ... }
```

and then use it inside the tinynmce.init like this:

```
tinymce.init({
    ...
    paste_preprocess : myFunction(pl, o)
});
```

But it's not working...

The only configs I've seen usually are:

```
tinymce.init({
...
    paste_preprocess: function(pl, o) { ... }
});
```

so, anonymous functions, am I right?

Is there a way to achieve that with a declared function, or is this only working as the usual practice 
`paste_preprocess: function() {}`?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The actual configuration option expects an anonymous function so if you want to externalize your function you could do something like this:

```
paste_postprocess: function(editor, fragment) {
    myFunction(editor, fragment);
}
```

Elsewhere you can define your function that you want to run:

```
function myFunction(editor, fragment) {
    console.log('myFunction called!');
}
```

Then you can put the real paste logic in `myFunction(editor, fragment)` and as long as that function exists on the page at runtime things will work.

This would allow you to load different processing functions depending on need while having one configuration.

Comment: I updated my question, thanks for your answer! 
I guess the problem comes when I try to pass something to myFunction(pl, o), maybe those objects only exist inside the scope of tinymce.init({}), and that's why it's not working.